# Adobe DTM Capturing Change of Select

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I thought this would be straightforward but I don't see how to use DTM to detect the onChange of a select?  If I choose "change" in the event type, I get a dropdown to select a data element which is not what I want. So how do I detect the changing of a select on a page? I don't care about the value it changes to, only the fact that it changed?

```
<select id="mainForm:cont_appRequest_customers__0_identityDocuments__0_identityDocumentType:decoin:appRequest_customers__0_identityDocuments__0_identityDocumentType" name="mainForm:cont_appRequest_customers__0_identityDocuments__0_identityDocumentType:decoin:appRequest_customers__0_identityDocuments__0_identityDocumentType" size="1"> <option value="org.jboss.seam.ui.NoSelectionConverter.noSelectionValue" selected="selected">-- Choose one --</option>
<option value="DRIVERS_LICENSE">Driver's License</option>
<option value="STATE_ID">State issued ID Card</option>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your **Event Based Rule** `>` **Conditions** `>` **Event Type**

Select **`Forms`** `>` `change`

Leave **`to value`** and the text field for it unchecked and blank.

A "`Select Data Element`" dropdown will appear - Ignore it (leave it as the default "`Select One`" value).

Target the `<select>` element using **Element Tag or Selector** field as normal.

**Side Note:** (*this is what you mentioned in your question as the problem*). 
I *think* the "`Select Data Element`" dropdown is supposed to be for if you want to bind the `change` to a **Data Element** - in your case, the `<select>` element to a (css) data element - but I don't think this is working as Adobe intended.

I *think* the intention was for it to effectively be the same as the `dataelementchanged` **Event Type**, but the **Rule** still expects you to fill out an **Element Tag or Selector** anyways, even if you select a **Data Element**. IOW you have to fill out the rest of the **Rule** fields anyway, so I don't really see a benefit of setting up a **Data Element**, too. On that note..

**Alternative**

An alternative way of doing this is to create a **Data Element** of **Type** `CSS Selector`. In the **CSS Selector Chain**, point to your `<select>` element, and for **`get the value of`**, select "`value`".

Next, in the **Event Based Rule**, choose **Event Type** of `dataelementchanged`, and then select your **Data Element** in the dropdown.

**Note:** I only mention this alternative for the sake of pointing out what I *think* the intended purpose of that "`Select Data Element`" dropdown is for, for the **`Forms`** `>` `change` method. But as mentioned, the **Rule** makes you fill out the rest of the fields anyway, so I don't really see the point in doing it for that first method. But this is how you'd do it as its own separate method. In practice, I don't recommend this method, because it has a higher performance cost than the first method (*`dataelementchanged` type works by polling the data element every 100ms*)